# Who created exponential regression? Is this the first transcendental function used in regression?

Tags: regression, history

Who created exponential regression? Is this the first transcendental function used in regression?

Fisher's paper just mentioned the polynomial version.

http://psychclassics.yorku.ca/Fisher/Methods/chap5.htm

I mean any forms with e's. For example,

\begin{align}
Y &= aX^b e^u  \\
Y &= ae^{bX}+u
\end{align}

I guess [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2236240?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) may be the first one, but I am not sure.

My original view of regression in this question is Fisher's regression, which stressed, for example, dependent random variables are conditional on independent random variables. I provided the link at the very beginning. However, some have provided answers out of my expectation.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by exponential regression? I can think of several possible things you might mean.

Comment: I think this is too open without clarification.

Comment: Apart from the question, does anyone know how to convert the symbols coded by MathJax into an image file? This can be done in editing Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, it was in 1825 when Benjamin Gompertz introduced an exponential function for age in the estimation of mortality tables. His formulation remains in wide use today in fields as diverse as actuarial science, marketing and technology. *Gompertz growth* is the origin for many models of the diffusion of technology and new product adoption, e.g., Rogers' adoption curve or the Bass-Anderson models used in marketing.

> The Gompertz–Makeham law states that the human death rate is the sum of an age-independent component (the Makeham term, named after William Makeham) and an age-dependent component (the Gompertz function, named after Benjamin Gompertz), which increases exponentially with age

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz%E2%80%93Makeham_law_of_mortality

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Gompertz

Comment: Interesting. These questions are tricky if only because they are so sensitive to definitions. For example, in what sense is this regression? If use of exponentials with some reference to empirical situations is what qualifies here, then there are, I think, earlier uses e.g. Newton on cooling.

Comment: Newton's law of cooling is not in random terms.

Comment: Then there's *Riccati's equation*, which predates Gompertz by 100 years and may be the original quadratic function for ODEs -- but it's nonlinear in the variables, not the parameters.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Comment: @user2986288 Neither is the Gompertz-Makeham law "in random terms" without an anachronistic interpretation, so far as I can tell. In any case, my point was that talking about a function with some attention to data is a extraordinarily broad interpretation of regression. I don't have a clear-cut answer to this because there are many different answers depending on precise interpretation of terms and it would be a substantial historical project to track them down.

Comment: +1 We might at least say that Gompertz' mortality as interpreted after a time would be a potential candidate for exponential regression.